# MySQL Event scheduler not generating CSV

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, jobs, event

The scheduler seems to be running from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS` but there is no CSV output.

The event scheduler has to automatically produce a csv to pass on the data to another system.  It's like integrating 2 systems through the csv, maybe not the optimum way.

The version of MySQL is 5.6.25.  What can be the issue?

The event is as below:

```
DROP EVENT x.tbl_event;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT  x.tbl_event
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 30 minute 
DO BEGIN
            select @sent := max(id) FROM x.TBL_COUNT;
            select @val := max(submission_id) FROM x.tbl_form;
             IF @sent < @val THEN
              SET @sql_stmt:= concat("select submission_id, application_type, applicant_name,
             applicant_nic,applicant_email,applicant_address_line1, applicant_address_line2,applicant_tel,
             applicant_mobile,association_name,association_registrationno,
             association_address_line1, association_address_line2,position_applicant,no_members, submission_date, no_of_guests 
             from x.tbl_form where submission_id>@sent and application_type !=''
             INTO OUTFILE 'C:/output", DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d_%H%i%s'), ".csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'");
             PREPARE extrct FROM @sql_stmt;
             EXECUTE extrct;
             DEALLOCATE PREPARE extrct;
             INSERT INTO TBL_COUNT(id, datecreated) VALUES(@val, NOW());
            END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The column `last_executed` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS` seems to indicate that the event gets triggered (and so my code runs), and yet I get no output file.

Comment: Please run `SELECT * FROM information_schema.events WHERE event_schema='x' AND event_name='tbl_event'\G` and post the output

Comment: RECURRING,NULL,30,MINUTE,"STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION","2016-03-24 15:59:26",NULL,ENABLED,"NOT PRESERVE","2016-03-24 15:59:26","2016-03-24 15:59:26","2016-03-30 13:29:26",,1,utf8,utf8_general_ci,utf8_general_ci